# robust wrapper for os.system in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, os.system

I am trying to write a robust wrapper function for os.system on python.
I saw below code in [tensorflow github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/4c238139674cec8d3b293e0fbbc71b6d2ddba144/third_party/gpus/crosstool/clang/bin/crosstool_wrapper_driver_rocm.tpl)

```
def system(cmd):
  """Invokes cmd with os.system().
  Args:
    cmd: The command.
  Returns:
    The exit code if the process exited with exit() or -signal
    if the process was terminated by a signal.
  """
  retv = os.system(cmd)
  if os.WIFEXITED(retv):
    return os.WEXITSTATUS(retv)
  else:
    return -os.WTERMSIG(retv)
```

However, python docs said, WTERMSIG "should be employed only if WIFSIGNALED() is true.".
so can we assume "else clause" already indicates WIFSIGNALED() is true. If we cannot, then what should return if WIFSIGNALED() is false, just return retv? like below

```
  if os.WIFEXITED(retv):
    return os.WEXITSTATUS(retv)
  elif os.WIFSIGNALED(retv):
    return -os.WTERMSIG(retv)

  return retv
```

thanks

Comment: You should probably replace the whole thing with calls to the `subprocess` module, which gives you a great deal more control.

Comment: Indeed,  you seem to be reinventing https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0324/ (which was subsequently updated significantly with the introduction of `subprocess.run`).